# The word "title" breaks simple Matrix conditional

Tags: matrix

Just found a super strange bug which is breaking a basic Matrix conditional.

The conditional is:

```
{if caption != ''}
```

And if the caption is this:

> Gérard Depardieu in the role of the title Rasputin, dir. by Irakli Kvirkadze (2013) this year's closing film

an error is caused:

```
Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable: {if "Gérard Depardieu in the role of the "Lights, camera, inaction: is Moscow International Film Festival doomed to mediocrity?" Rasputin, dir. by Irakli Kvirkadze (2013) this year's clo" != ''}
```

Because the word "title" is missing from the error, it looks like EE is trying to parse it.

What causes this and what is the fix?

---

Just an update - using Matrix 2.5.5, and EE 2.5.5.

Comment: Did you try removing title from the caption to see if the error persists? Also, try removing all quotes from your caption for good measure.

Comment: @JérômeCoupé yes I did remove it; that's how I know that's the bug. :-) There is no way I can tell my clent that they can't use "title" or quotes on their captions...

Comment: Have you tried {if "{caption}" != ''}

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding var_prefix to the matix loop?

eg:  {matrix_field var_prefix="var"}{if var:caption!=""}{matrix_field}

This should escape it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work. The error persists.